# Django ArrayField on Frontend Form?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently in the process of rebuilding my WordPress website into a full Django web app. With WordPress, I had made great use of the awesome Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and I'm struggling to get the same functionality with Django. One field in particular with ACF is called a "Repeater Field" that lets me click a button to add another row to an array.

I did manage to get something similar working with Django, but only in the Admin part. I've used this plugin "Django Better Admin ArrayField" - https://github.com/gradam/django-better-admin-arrayfield and it displays the arrayfield exactly as I want:

[Django Better Admin ArrayField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggzD.png)

How can I get this to work on the frontend of the site, like in a user-submitted form?

Comment: You can do this using [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) and here you are an [example](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :)